# After taking permission of DOCUMENT_TREE,its real path shows access denied

Tags: java, android

I take DOCUMENT_TREE uri read permission, and i have to copy its video to other folder, so after all we find that if i can get actual path then i can copy that file to other Folder,some methods of get path shows Error No such directory, but finally a method shows access denied that folder.

so basically two question here generated

1. is READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE have to use, to that specific folder,do Play console reject my app to use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my status saver application??
2. how can take that specific folder permission with DOCUMENT_TREE to not show that folder access denied??

I take DOCUMENT_TREE uri read permission, and i have to copy its video to other folder, so after all we find that if i can get actual path then i can copy that file to other Folder,some methods of get path shows Error No such directory, but finally a method shows access denied that folder.

Comment: "its real path shows access denied" -- there is no "real path". There is no requirement for the document tree to represent anything on the filesystem of the device. "if i can get actual path then i can copy that file to other Folder" -- you do not need a filesystem path to copy content. You can use `DocumentFile` to traverse the tree, get (or create) the `Uri` for a document, and use `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` or `OutputStream` on that content.

Comment: @CommonsWare  can you pls elaborate, how to use Content resolver and I/O stream to save video file from that uri(eg:content://Android/primary/com.xyz/---/xyz.mp4) , i have searched almost every platform, not found Content Resolver use to save the Video file from uri  , even not from video recording...

Comment: Call `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`, such as your `Activity`, to get [a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver). Call `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`, to get an `InputStream` to read in the content identified by the `Uri`. Or, call `openOutputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`, to get an `OutputStream` to write content to the location identified by your `Uri`.

Comment: FWIW, I cover the use of `ContentResolver` in the context of the Storage Access Framework in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-content-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).